# flow-type equivalent to 'as const' assertion in typescript

Tags: flowtype

surprisingly enough couldn't find an answer for this in StackOverflow, is there an equivalent of typescript 'as const' assertion in flow?

```js
const realyConstObj = {key1: 'val1', key2: 'val2'}

// current type that is being infered:
typeof realyConstObj    // {|key1: string, key2: string|}
       // desired type is: {key1: 'val1', key2: 'val2'}

// in typescript
const realyConstObj = {key1: 'val1', key2: 'val2'} as const // will give the deisired outcome

// in flow i have to do:
const realyConstObj:{key1: 'val1', key2: 'val2'} = {key1: 'val1', key2: 'val2'}
// quiet annoing... is there an alternative?
```

found an [open proposal](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/7970) for this feature in flow repo, but this 2 year old any maybe something updated since then

Comment: So basically what you're asking for is, when you create an object you'd like the type inference to reflect string literals as opposed to the type of the property value itself?

Comment: nothing is opposed to anything else here, it's up to the developer intention - sometimes you intend to declare a constant object so 'val1' is not a string - it's just 'val1' - a string literal. There is no contradiction here